# SVG Masks with relative-positionning children in ForeignObjects

Tags: svg, mask, css-position

I've a matter with this code, why do the foreignObject children go out from the mask ?
Here's my code http://jsbin.com/ehukom/2/

`.pos`and `.pos2`should be in the mask... Where's my error?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your errors are

1. trying only Chrome (have a look at Firefox as well) and
2. assuming that Chrome is right and you're in error.

The only good fix to this problem I can think of is [reporting a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry).

Comment: You're right, I tested it months ago on Safari and not on Firefox... https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=355365&thanks=355365&ts=1395580360